# Magento "My Orders Page" returns 404 - database related

Tags: php, database, magento, http-status-code-404

We currently have Magento 1.7.0.2 installed since April and everything has been fine without issue, however an issue has arrived.

Certain users, when clicking "My Account" on the frontend will get shown a 404 error page.
Not every user sees it, and if they click "View Order" on an individual order from the recent orders section of My Account, that order will display fine.

After some digging, I've narrowed it down to the "sales_flat_order_item" table. If I go through each order and delete a certain item related to that order, or simply change the product_id - the page will then show fine. The product exists in Magento so it can't be that.

I've tried re-indexing, deleting cache - everything I can think of.

Does anyone have any suggestions as what would cause the 404? Going through 3000+ records, finding which item is causing the issue and deleting it is NOT an option for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this issue here's the solution.

The site had been working fine for months so don't know this stopped working BUT copied /sales/order/history.phtml out of the base theme and put it into our own (it didn't exist to start with) and edited line 63

from

```
if ($this->helper('sales/reorder')->canReorder($_order)) :
```

to

```
if(Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/reorder/allow')):
```

Which fixed my issues.

Not sure why that bit of code would break, nor why it would show a 404 page since the output would have already started and shouldn't redirect?